# css / html - spread child divs across parent div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My issue is that I have a div (id=service-section-container) which contains 3 divs (class=service-section) which are shifted to the left of their parent div. I haven't found an efficient way to center the group of child divs using margins as using pixels would have a different result of different screens where as percentage didn't do the trick.

It's probably a simple fix which I couldn't solve with my lack of experience, hence why I'd really appreciate your help.

Example can be found at the link: http://jsfiddle.net/6tob3q1z/2/

Note: You might need to zoom out on the fiddle to understand what i'm talking about as at 1000px the divs in question (service-section) will re-position to on top of each other

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width", initial-scale=1>
        <title> Learning Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
<!------------------------Menu------------------------> 

        <nav id="menu-bar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"><!--The menu bar-->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container"><!--Menu bar toggle-->
                    <span class="sr-only">Show and hide the navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button><!--End of Menu bar toggle-->
                <a class="navba-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="images/hexagon.PNG" width="40px">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" > <!--Menu bar ul-->
                    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About-us <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Driving directions</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                           
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!--End of menu bar UL-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav><!--End of menu bar-->
        <header id="cover">
            <h1 class="site-name">Hello Clarice</h1>
            <h4 class="slogan">It's nice to see you again.</h4>
        </header>
<!------------------------End of menu------------------------>  

<!------------------------Services------------------------> 
        <div id="service-section-container" class="row">
            <div id="section-title">
                <h1>Services</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="service-section col-md-4 ">
                <h4>Web design</h4>
                <p>This is a jumbotron class. It would span the width of a single column.</p>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Read more</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="service-section col-md-4">
                <h4>Online Marketing</h4>
                <p>This is a jumbotron class. It would span the width of a single column.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Read more</button>
            </div>
            <div class="service-section col-md-4">
                <h4>IT Consultancy</h4>
                <p>This is a jumbotron class. It would span the width of a single column.</p>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Read more</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row footer">
        <p class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark pull-right">Copyright</p>
    </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**:

```
    html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
@font-face{
    font-family:josefin;
    src: url('fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf');
}
#cover{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('background.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 494px;
    height:100vh;
    background-size:cover;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    /*margin-bottom:10px;*/
}

h1, h4{
    margin:0;
}
.row{

}
.footer{
    margin:0 !important;
    background-color:#ECF0F1;
}
p{
    margin:0 auto 20px !important;
    max-width:600px !important;
}

#menu-bar{
    margin-bottom:0 !important;
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border:0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar a{
    color:black !important;
}

/**********************Services section**********************/
#service-section-container{
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #F2F1EF;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.service-section p, button{
    margin:10px !important;
}
#section-title{
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#section-title h1{
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #D2D7D3;
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:40px 10px 20px 10px !important;
    padding:20px;
}
.service-section{
    border-radius:2px !important;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0 20px;
    margin:1%;
    width:30% !important;
    border-radius:2px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

.service-section h4{
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:150%;
}

.service-section p{
    text-align:center;
}
.button-container{
    text-align:center;
}
.service-section button{
    margin: 10px auto !important;
    padding:5px;

    display:block;
    background-image:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
/****>1000px screen services section****/
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
    .service-section{
        width:85% !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
        padding:0 !important;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Is something like this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/atxzpe8b/

Comment: Tag your question with "bootstrap" so someone who knows that will see your question and likely solve this easily for you.

Comment: @RyanWheale. Thanks for your reply. The fiddle is almost perfect, however it looks like the right margin is wider than the left. Would it be possible to assign the same width to both left and right margin of the group of divs ?

Comment: that 3 div will always be centered and side by side each other? what browsers support are within your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would use wrapper for those 3 service divs and set a width for it and center that div

```css
.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.section {
  width: 32.3%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your very efficient reply.

What you provided is very close to fitting perfectly, however it looks like the right margin is wider than the left.

Would it be possible to assign the same width to both left and right of the group of divs ?

Comment: its because of the width of section just make it 32.3%. hope it solves your problem. check the edit

Comment: not sure would OP concern, but around 660px the right div will move down

Comment: if you need it without breaking and exactly center. you could use css calc(). but it has some browser compatibility issues.

width: calc(33.3% - 6px); (6px is margin gap)