# Centre a responsive thumbnail gallery

Tags: html, css, thumbnails, image-gallery, twitter-bootstrap-2

Here is my site:

http://www.gregorydanelian.comule.com/ken

I want thumbnail gallery to be centred at all times but I am having trouble doing this.

I know I can use

```
text-align: center;
```

On the parent element and then set the thumbnails like so:

```
display: inline-block;
```

However nothing is working, the thumbnails always float left.

I have tried adding media queries to force the margin from left (for example):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.thumbnails{
margin-left: 40px!important;   
}
}
```

But there must be an easier way to just get the **ul** to centre no matter what the width is.

How can I centre the thumbnail gallery on all browser widths?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722897/css-html-spread-child-divs-across-parent-div/33723043#33723043

Comment: @Shakee93 bro I think you linked this question by accident

Comment: you probably have something else that's wrong. text-align: center with inline-block should work. You probably have some grandparent element floating left or with the default "text-align: left"

Comment: @Ahmad Jazakallah. Updated now

Comment: here's a fiddle showing a very simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/cdus2fn0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these changes and remove those `left-margins` you set `!important` on `ul`

```
.thumbnails > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.thumbnails {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Important**: Add this to end of your `css/mystyles.css` file.

Comment: Testing this shortly!

Comment: Do you mean add CSS file link to end of HTML ?

Comment: No i mean add this css code to end of your css file.

Comment: This is the correct answer in my case. Thank you so much. I did try something similar but I believe the other CSS was to blame.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS media query

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.thumbnails {
    max-width:1200px
}
```

you may have to adjust media queries for multiple screens.

Comment: test it @AbdulAhmad, I've got a 21" screen and adding that media query got the thumbnails to the center of the screen. There is also margin-left assigned to .thumbnails.

Comment: I know you can define a width and get it centred however I need them centred without defining a specific width. This is a fall back option and does answer the question in a sense!

Comment: @Danelian, I agree. also note that when you are looking for other options you may have to reconsider the margin-left on thumbnails